# What's DataTransferItemList and what is DataTransferItemList.add doing?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

So I'm trying to understand [`paste`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27262428/607407) and `copy` API in Google Chrome. I don't understand either.

As of copy, you'll probably want to use javascript to **add something in clipboard**. I'm working with images (strings work well actually<sup>**1**</sup>):

```
//Get DataTransferItemList
var files = items.items;

if(files) {
  console.log(files);
  //Create blob from canvas
  var blob = Blob.fromDataURL(_this.editor.selection.getSelectedImage().toDataURL("image/png"));

  var file;
  try {
    //Try to create file from blob, which may fail
    file = new File([blob], "image.png", {type:"image/png"}); 
  }
  catch(e) {
    return false;
  }
  if(file) {
    //I think this should clear previous data from clipboard
    files.clear();
    //Add a file as image/png
    files.add(file, "image/png");
  }
  //console.log(files.add(file));
}
```

The problem is, that I don't really know how does that `add` method work. I found [this "*documentation*" for DataTransferItemList](http://html5index.org/Drag%20and%20Drop%20-%20DataTransferItemList.html#add) which says:

```
    add(any data, optional DOMString type)
```

What's *any data*? (how can anybody even write this in documentation?) While *something* is added to clipboard, I don't know what it is. I can't paste it anywhere - except Chrome. If I inspect paste event with my copied file, this is in DataTransferItemList:

[image: DataTransferItemList]

It can be converted to File, but if I try to turn it back to `<img>`:

```
ImageEditorKeyboard.prototype.processFile = function(file) {
  //File reader converts files to something else
  var reader = new FileReader();
  //Refference to this class
  var _this = this;
  //happens when the file is loaded
  reader.onload = function(event) {
    var img = new Image;
    img.onload = function() {
      _this.processImage(this);
    };
    img.src = event.target.result;
  }; // data url!
  //Read file
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
```

I get the error<sup>**2**</sup>:

[image: GET data: net::ERR_INVALID_URL]

If I log the value of `event.target.result` it turns out that the data was empty:

```
console.error("String '", event.target.result, "' ain't a valid URL!");
```

[image: String ' data: ' ain't a valid URL!]

- *Q:* What is the exact specification of `DataTransferItemList`, it's methods and properties, especially the `.add` method?

<sup>**1:** To add string to clipboard (during copy event of course!), call this: `event.clipboardData.setData(data, "text/plain");`. The second argument doesn't seem to have any functionality - using `image/png` will not do anything.</sup>

<sup>**2:** Funny thing is that this [error can't be caught](http://jsfiddle.net/Darker/vom2rhgf/1/).</sup>

Comment: 1. afaik, text/html works as well as text/plain, but there's a small number of acceptable formats, not just anything works. 2. i know the interface provides access to pasting files, but i don't believe that you can copy files to the clipboard from js yet. (i could be wrong)

Comment: @dandavis The evidence above says that I can copy in clipboard but it's not fully functional. Maybe the data are not really in clipboard but just in google chrome memory. I found no convenient program to discover what's being (in hex or binary) added to clipboard.